# react js : detect page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reload

I am new to react.js.
I have a simple page with table. When I reload the page, state is getting lost.
Is there a way to detect the browser refresh ?

Comment: Single page apps shouldn’t reload the whole page, just if you don’t want to hard-resets your state.

Comment: its not a single page app.

Comment: @learning_vba You don't need `renderTable();` in your `MainHandler.js` Because that'll be handled by `Dashboard.js` independently.

Comment: thing is I dont want to change the existing logic. Is there anyway to detect browser refresh?

Answer (score 5):

The event [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) is executed just before window browser is being refreshed. Event is cancellable.

```js
window.beforeunload = (e) => {
  console.log('Stop this');
  e.preventDefault()
  e.returnValue = '';
};
```

When using React an option is to take control in your Application component, or your most higher order component, in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method as @georgim suggested instead `componentWillUnmount` as I first suggested, and manage there what you want to achieve.

Comment: what do you think about componentDidMount in the top level component? (to detect reload)

Comment: @giorgim I have been trying it and besides it is better to use the `beforeunload` event listener, indeed it is more reliable to apply the logic in `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 0):

With [react-beforeunload][1] you can track the page changes easily

```
import { useBeforeunload } from 'react-beforeunload'
const App = () => {
  const [preventMultiSubmit, setPreventMultiSubmit] = useState(false)
}
 const pageRefConf = useBeforeunload((event) => {
    if (preventMultiSubmit) {
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  })
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', pageRefConf)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', pageRefConf)
    }
  }, [])
```

This worked for me. I hope this one will work for you too.
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beforeunload

Answer (score -1):

Try this one. This worked for me.

```
if (window.performance) {
  if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    alert( "This page is reloaded" );
  } else {
    alert( "This page is not reloaded");
  }
}
```

Comment: this API is deprecated