# React | How to detect Page Refresh (F5)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, page-refresh

I'm using [React js](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html). I need to detect `page refresh`. When user hits refresh icon or press F5, I need to find out the event.

I tried with [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368578/react-js-detect-page-refresh) by using javascript functions

I used javascript function `beforeunload` still no luck.

```
onUnload(event) { 
  alert('page Refreshed')
}

componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload)
}
```

here I have full code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vtu3x3)

Comment: Why not just check for `e.keyCode === 116`, which is the F5 key?
Here is an example of how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34634290/2127769

Comment: There may be two scenarios browser refresh button click and F5 press

Comment: Your code works fine

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Place this in the constructor:

```
if (window.performance) {
  if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    alert( "This page is reloaded" );
  } else {
    alert( "This page is not reloaded");
  }
}
```

It will work, please see this example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cydncm).

Comment: But there is the problem. It  is getting triggered even page changing. not only page refresh. I need only page refresh

Comment: Just change the content of conditions

Comment: I'm using react router. when I switch menu It is getting triggered

Comment: Please see the alert text, if page refresh an alert "This page is reloaded" will be triggered , else another alert "this page is not reloaded" will be triggered.
So you can use just the first condition

Comment: @MariaJeysinghAnbu is saying corrent it trigger the refresh alert even route changed in IE. In IE even if user changes route its values is 1 but in chrome its working differently

Comment: will this work if the user clicks on the refresh button instead F5?

Comment: How do you do something AFTER refresh has complete?

Comment: This is deprecated now. `PerformanceNavigationTiming` should be used instead.

Comment: `Performance.navigation` is deprecated, see [Performance.navigation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation)

Answer (score 38):

If you're using React Hook, UseEffect you can put the below changes in your component. It worked for me

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", alertUser);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", alertUser);
    };
  }, []);
  const alertUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = "";
  };
```

Comment: `beforeUnload` listener not only fired on refresh, but also when you are navigating with address bar, so it might fired unintentionally. Hence using return value as a flagging is wise thing to do.

Answer (score 20):

It is actually quite straightforward, this will add the default alert whenever you reload your page.

In this answer you will find:

1. Default usage
2. Alert with validation

## 1. Default Usage

### Functional Component

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return true;
    };

    return () => {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    };
}, []);
```

### Class Component

```
componentDidMount(){
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return true;
    };
}

componentDidUnmount(){
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
```

---

## 2. Alert with validation

You can put validation to only add alert whenever the condition is `true`.

### Functional Component

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (condition) {
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            return true;
        };
    }

    return () => {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    };
}, [condition]);
```

### Class Component

```
componentDidMount(){
    if (condition) {
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            return true;
        };
    }
}

componentDidUnmount(){
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
```

Comment: How can i use this code in react.js class component ?

Comment: @Mayur Vaghasiya, you can use `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUnmount` function for the Class Component. The one on my useEffect is for `componentDidMount` and the one on my useEffect's return is for `componentDidUnmount`. I'll edit my answer later when I have the time.

Comment: Is there any way to modify the message in the prompt that comes after reloading?

Comment: Note: If you dont return anything in the "onbeforeunload" function it will hide the confirmation dialog "Do you really want to leave this page?"

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately currently accepted answer cannot be more considered as acceptable since performance.navigation.type is [deprecated](https://w3c.github.io/navigation-timing/#obsolete)

The newest API for that is experimental ATM.
As a workaround I can only suggest to save some value in redux (or whatever you use) store to indicate state after reload and on first route change update it to indicate that route was changed not because of refresh.

Comment: didn't think redux survived a browser refresh

Comment: It is not, but it could be used to identify route change by setting some global state flag.
In case the flag has default value, it means we are in state after refresh, otherwise it is the route change.

Comment: @nrmad - I believe, redux can retain if you can prevent refresh.

Answer (score 11):

Your code seems to be working just fine, your alert won't work because you aren't stopping the refresh. If you `console.log('hello')` the output is shown.

UPDATE ---

This should stop the user refreshing but it depends on what you want to happen.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        this.onUnload();
        return "";
    }.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: can I call any function in that `onUnload` function? becoz I tried it seems not working.

Comment: You need to prompt the user with something that will stop the refresh. What function are you trying to place inside `onUnload`? I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Only on page refresh I have to call a function like this `this.props.actions.loaddata()`

Comment: Thank You. I think, It has  been called before page load. I need after user refresh the page

Comment: Abdellatif seems to have a better solution than mine for that.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using either REDUX or CONTEXT API then its quite easy. You can check the REDUX or CONTEXT state variables. When the user refreshes the page it reset the CONTEXT or REDUX state and you have to set them manually again. So if they are not set or equal to the initial value which you have given then you can assume that the page is refreshed.

Comment: Initially I found this approach useful, but then I found it had created a bug for me, so now what I'm doing is storing a string prop called currentPage in one of my redux reducers from my componentDidMount but checking its value before setting it, to ensure that the previous page was a different page and not simply a reload. Time will tell if this is a good approach or not

Answer (score 0):

'navigation' is deprecated, instead, add this to the constructor:

```
const navigationEntries = window.performance.getEntriesByType('navigation');
if (navigationEntries.length > 0 && navigationEntries[0].type === 'reload') {
 console.log("Page was reloaded");
}
```

Make sure to wrap it in the useEffect(). The reason for using useEffect in this case is to ensure that the code runs at the appropriate time during the component lifecycle.

When you place the code directly inside the function body without useEffect, it will be executed whenever the component function is called, which could lead to unexpected behavior.

By using useEffect with an empty dependency array ([]), you ensure that the code runs only once, after the initial render of the component. This approach is generally preferred when you want to perform initialization tasks or set up event listeners in a React component.

```
function MyComponent(){

   useEffect(() => {
     const navigationEntries = window.performance.getEntriesByType('navigation');
     if (navigationEntries.length > 0 && navigationEntries[0].type === 'reload') {
       console.log("Page was reloaded");
     }
   }, []);

}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: this triggers when you change a page