# How to clear props.location.state on refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am navigating to another page where in am passing some data like so:

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: "/someotherpage",
  state: { somedata: somedata }
});
```

Now on `/someotherpage`, I have a condition in my `render()` method to show a component depending on whether `this.props.location.state` is not null.

```
{this.props.location.state && (
    <SomeComponent>
        {this.props.location.state.somedata}
    </SomeComponent>
)}
```

It's working. However, when I refresh the page, `<SomeComponent>` still shows up as it still has the `this.props.location.state.somedata` stored even if I refresh. How do I clear `this.props.location.state` back to null when refreshing the page? (It seems to clear though when navigating away, only on refresh it gets retained.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
history.replace('', null);
```

Comment: Close enough.. I used history.replace('/currentroute', null);

Comment: didn't work for me, I've this error `Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'History'`

Comment: Check your import. I think you are importing the wrong History module. It should be import { History } from 'history';

Comment: `history.replace('' null);`
Isn't working for me. It's redirecting me to /
But using `history.replace(location.pathname, null);` is working fine!

Answer (score 12):

Use `window.history.replaceState(null, '')` to clear the location state after the value is consumed.

[MDN Web Docs:  History.replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState)

> The History.replaceState() method modifies the current history entry, replacing it with the stateObj, title, and URL passed in the method parameters
>
> **Syntax:** history.replaceState(stateObj, title, [url]);

It's safe to leave title blank and url is optional.

The main point is that **It doesn't cause another refresh.**

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it wipes out all the history and it affects the forward button. Any other idea of how to fix this?

Comment: it's working thanks! this should be the correct answer 

Comment: `history.replace('' null);`
Isn't working for me. It's redirecting me to /
But using `history.replace(location.pathname, null);` is working fine!

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can add function like below to differentiate ***page refresh*** from ***this.props.history.push*** as below:

```
isPageRefreshed() {
    return window.performance && performance.navigation.type === 1;
  }
```

Then when you want to check if it is refreshed or redirected from other page, you can use like that

```
{!this.isPageRefreshed && this.props.location.state && (
    <SomeComponent>
        {this.props.location.state.somedata}
    </SomeComponent>
)}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50026758/8777471

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the current history entry's state to `null` like this:

```
const { state, pathname } = useLocation();

history.replace(pathname, null);
```