# How to redirect to another page when the current page is refreshed Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to redirect to previous page when the current page is reloaded or refreshed,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onUnload = this.onUnload.bind(this);
    this.onbeforeunload= this.onbeforeunload.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      show_answers: [],
      other_data: [],
      question: "",
      answer: "",
      id: 0,
    };
  }



onUnload() {
    console.log("reloads")
this.context.router.push('/getanswer');
}

onbeforeunload(){
  console.log("reloadsssss")
this.context.router.push('/getanswer');
}
```

I have tried above way but not working any suggestions.

Comment: By refresh do you mean browser's F5?

Comment: Yes if user reloads it

Comment: @NabeelAyub Well it makes a difference for implements

Comment: So how can I manage this?

Comment: @NabeelAyub pass a state prop on redirection and set it to null on particular page. You can check for it in this particular component

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026028/react-how-to-detect-page-refresh-f5

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  this.context.router.push('/getanswer');
}
```

whenever page loads componentDidUpdate method will get invoke and it will redirect into previous page.

Comment: this will reroute even when redirected @Sajish

Comment: This method won't trigger when user reloads a page. (from documentation - "This method is not called for the initial render.")

Answer (score 0):

ReactJs don't have any method to listen reload events. Use this plain Javascript event handler:

```
window.onbeforeunload = (e) => {
  this.context.router.push('/getanswer');
};
```

Usa can also put this (on constructor):

```
constructor(props) {
  if (window.performance) {
    if (window.performance.navigation.type == 1) {
      //This page is reloaded
      this.context.router.push('/getanswer');
    }
  }
}
```