# ReactJs applying javascript correctly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 pages reactjs application with a bootstrap template. I am using react-router to handle the page transitions.
So I have a index.js file containing something like:

```
function App() {
   return(
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/page1/">
            <Page1 />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/page2">
            <Page2 />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
}
```

In my index.html file, I defined some js functions to apply some effects to the pages, like a carousel and things like this. The weird thing is that when I reach page2 from clicking the link on page1 the js effects are applied, but when I refresh it the js effects are not applied...

this is my page2 file (I stripped all the unnecessary stuff for simplicity):

```
function Page2(){
useEffect(() => {
   window.applyEffects();
})

return(
  some jsx here...
)
}
```

am I doing something wrong here?

**EDIT**

I realised I forgot to add an important detail. I removed the useEffect and the call to window.applyEffects() in my component and the page renders as I would expect without the effect. If then I call window.applyEffects() from the developer console everything works fine. I suspect I should find a way to call the js function **AFTER** the page has been totally rendered. Is this doable?

**SOLVED**

I would like to thank everyone that replied and helped me in the right direction. I solved it by updating the useEffect hook like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');

  script.src = `${window.location.origin}/js/effects.js`;
  script.async = true;

  document.body.appendChild(script);

  return () => {
    document.body.removeChild(script);
  }
});
```

I created a file called effects.js in the js folder, and I load it by appending it to the dom every time the component loads... also I remember to remove it with the return. I leave this here hoping it could help someone in my same situation in the future!
Thank you stackoverflow community !

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you just want to run a piece of code every time page is reloaded, checking it out I found it
[React | How to detect Page Refresh (F5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026028/react-how-to-detect-page-refresh-f5)

and it seems what you are looking for.

Comment: I posted a similar comment to another answer stating the same but I guess the person deleted his answer. The `useEffect` hook will fire in an infinite look without the **array** dependency, thus firing the function inside. However, it seems that is not the case, I suspect he's not using the `window` object correctly.

Comment: try to add window in the dependency array, like useEffect(() => {
   window.applyEffects();
},[window]) 
or even window.applyEffects as I edited my answer

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried adding window in the dependency array and I get this error in the browser console: 

 React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'window'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Outer scope values like 'window' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component     

I get the same even if I add window.applyEffects in the array...

Comment: Yep there's no reason to add any global variables, including `window` itself, to a React dependency array.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I fixed it and updated the initial question with the solution

Answer (score 1):

I saw that you are using `window` object inside your code. Maybe that is the root of your problem. On the official documentation it says:

> Window Object The window object represents an open window in a
> browser.
>
> If a document contain frames ( tags), the browser creates one
> window object for the HTML document, and one additional window object
> for each frame.

...which kind of suggests that it will fire once the window is open in the browser, hence I'm not sure that it will **re-fire** once you refresh the page. Having the `useEffect` hook should fire away anything when a page refreshes because it **mounts** the component again.

I suggest look into how you are using the `window.applyEffects()`. [Here's a link to the official window documentation.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I fixed it and updated the initial question with the solution