# How can i handle page refresh event in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

I want to make a confirmation before user leaving the page. If he says ok then it would redirect to new page or cancel to leave.

but issue is that when user refresh page using **browser refresh btn** in google chrome that time below error occur

[image]

I tired this code but doesn't work in react.js please help

```
  window.hideWarning = false;
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
      if (!window.hideWarning) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = '';
      }
    });
```

Also try this code

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { return ''; }.bind(this);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React | How to detect Page Refresh (F5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026028/react-how-to-detect-page-refresh-f5)

Comment: @ToujouAya Its works ! but when user refresh the page using browser refresh button that time this error occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code it's work for me

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  if ("Some condition") {
     return '';
   }
 }.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use that

`winodow.location.reload(true)`
`winodow.location.reload(false)`

Comment: it doesn't work !, 

I want show confirmation before user leaving the page.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
console.log(window.performance.navigation)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).