# Cancel async Axios GET request - React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I have an Axios `GET` request that starts fetching an API when clicking a button. This request takes a long time (around a minute) and I would like to cancel it and start a new one when the button is clicked again.

Also, I would also like to be able to cancel the request if it is pending and I refresh the page.

I tried everything I found here on SO but nothing seems to work. I also read the Axios doc about cancelling : https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation.

All this lead me there :

#### Updated code (see edit below)

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let cancel;

function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getPairs() {
            try {
                if (cancel) {
                    cancel();
                }

                const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/binance/pairs?timeframe='+timeframe+'&strat='+strat, {
                    cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
                    cancel = c;
                    })
                });

                if (res.status === 200 || res.data.status === 'success') {
                    setPairs(res.data.pairs);
                    setReloadConfig(false);
                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                if (axios.isCancel(err)) {
                    console.log("cancelled");
                } else {
                throw err;
                }
            }
        }
    
        // reloadConfig is a React useState hook that is set to true when clicking a button 
        if (reloadConfig) {
            getPairs();
        }
    }, [reloadConfig]);
}

export default App;
```

Note that `reloadConfig` is a React `useState` hook that is set to true when clicking a button, therefore triggering the `useEffect` hook and the Axios request.

Problem is, if I click the button multiple times, no request is cancelled and a new one is created every time. I can see all the requests being treated in my terminal.

How can I cancel the last pending request and create a new one when clicking the button triggering the `useEffect` ?

Also, how can I cancel a pending request if I refresh the page ?

### ----- Edit -----

After twiking a bit with the code, I found out that placing `cancelToken` and `cancel` variables before the component function declaration made me move forward. Now, `cancel` is not `undefined` anymore and I get the `cancelled` message from the `catch` block :

```
catch (err) {
    if (axios.isCancel(err)) {
        console.log("cancelled");
    }
}
```

If I `console.log(cancel)`, it returns this :

```
ƒ cancel(message) {
    if (token.reason) {
      // Cancellation has already been requested
      return;
    }

    token.reason = new Cancel(message);
    resolvePromise(token.reason);
}
```

So it tells me cancellation was successful (if I understand correctly ?), but I can still see all the requests being logged in the backend terminal and still being processed. What's wrong with it ?

Thank you very much

### ----- Edit 2 -----

The solutions showed above all worked. The problem was a misunderstanding on my part : when I do a call to my API to fetch the results, the results are actually fetched by a library that itself fetches one URI per result, meaning that one call to my API makes multiple calls to another API via said library.

I can say the solutions showed above by the community worked because I tried them on a sandbox with a "normal" mock API. I think what happens in my case is that, the library I use with my API calls +200 URLs, so I guess one call was cancelled but not the other 199.

If anyone have a solution to cancel everything that would be great but I think that's more of a backend situation than frontend one at this point.

Thanks to everyone for your help and patience.

Comment: Is the cancel variable defined when the getPairs function is called? Try to add a console.log(cancel) when the function starts to see if it defined, if it's not, you may want to block a new action until the cancel is created.

About the cancel when user refreshes the page, see if one of those solutions works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026028/react-how-to-detect-page-refresh-f5

Comment: The `cancel` variable is declared in the body of the file (`App.js`, not in any function or anything), just before the `useEffect` hook, just as show in the code provided. When `console.log` on `cancel`, it is in fact `undefined`. What do you mean by "block a new action" ? Thanks

Comment: I edited the code and now I get the "cancellation message from `if (axios.isCancelled(err)) console.log('cancelled')`. But somehow, I can still see all the requests being processed in the backend terminal. Any idea ? (I edited the original post with more details). Thank you very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are depending on useEffect to fire up your request, you can use the cleanup function of useEffect to cancel your API request before a new one is executed.

```
function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
        let CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
        let source = CancelToken.source();
        async function getPairs() {
            try {

                const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/binance/pairs?timeframe='+timeframe+'&strat='+strat, {
                    cancelToken: source.token
                });

                if (res.status === 200 || res.data.status === 'success') {
                    setPairs(res.data.pairs);
                    setReloadConfig(false);
                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                if (axios.isCancel(err)) {
                    console.log("cancelled");
                } else {
                throw err;
                }
            }
        }
    
        // reloadConfig is a React useState hook that is set to true when clicking a button 
        if (reloadConfig) {
            getPairs();
        }

        return () => {
             source.cancel('Cancelled due to stale request');
        }
    }, [reloadConfig]);
}

export default App;
```

> Note that you should define your `cancel` variable within useEffect
> otherwise it will be re-initialzed to undefined on next render if you
> directly define it within the component.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work for me. `console.log(cancel)` shows that `cancel` is `undefined` in this case. I wrote the code exactly as you wrote it.

Comment: are you sure, your API didn't return a response before you tried to cancel it

Comment: Sure, the response from the API takes around one minute to come, and I clicked the button in just a few seconds. Any idea ?

Comment: I updated my answer with a different technique to use cancelToken. Do check and let me know if that solves your problem?

Comment: What it does now is block the new request from being fired up but still continues with the previous one. Thanks for helping, I greatly appreciate it

Comment: That is totally weird, Can you create a sandbox to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I tried it with a mock API in a sandbox and it works. I think the problem is that I'm calling the Binance API (crypto trading platform) to fetch the results of lot of cryptos (+200). I use a library to help with the Binance API. The problem is, when I call my API to fetch those cryptos, the library calls one URL per crypto listed. So each time I do one call via my API, the library makes +200. I guess one call from the library is cancelled but the other 199 go trough. Didn't think of this before but makes sense. Any idea if there is a solution to this ? Thanks a lot for your help and patience

Comment: If you can provide more details about the library, I will check it out.

Answer (score 3):

### June 2022 Update

`CancelToken` has been deprecated since Axios `v0.22.0` and should not be used in new projects (reference: https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation). Use `AbortController` instead, like so:

```js
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    async function getPairs() {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          "http://localhost:3000/binance/pairs?timeframe=" +
            timeframe +
            "&strat=" +
            strat,
          {
            signal: controller.signal,
          }
        );

        if (res.status === 200 || res.data.status === "success") {
          setPairs(res.data.pairs);
          setReloadConfig(false);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        if (axios.isCancel(err)) {
          console.log("cancelled");
        } else {
          throw err;
        }
      }
    }

    // reloadConfig: React useState hook set to true when clicking a button
    if (reloadConfig) {
      getPairs();
    }

    return () => {
      controller.abort();
    };
  }, [reloadConfig]);
}

export default App;
```

Happy coding! Ciao.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not a web problem, I can't give an accurate answer. Maybe you can consider using queue and broadcast(websocket) solution?

If you want to do something before refreshing the page, please refer to [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event.The code that executes the cancel request in the event callback.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I tried it with the edits I made to the original post (putting `CancelToken` and `cancel` variable declarations above the component function declaration) and also with those same variables juste above the `useEffect` hook. It gives the same result as the edit I made in the post : I get the `cancelled` message from the `catch` block (from `if (axios.isCancel(err)) console.log("cancelled")`) but still can see all the requests being processed on the backend terminal. Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: @Tom687 so sorry. I can only give advice on this issue.

Comment: No worries, thank you very much for your input

Answer (score 0):

Think you should change implementation like this to ensure you're avoiding memory leaks and handling errors. Using a separate hook for the axios request will also decouple your component and request code.

The main issue you have is that you're not getting the token from `source` i.e. `const { token: cancelToken, cancel } = source;`

```
const useFetchPairs = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    pairs: null,
    isLoading: false,
    error: null,
  });
  const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
  const source = CancelToken.source();
  const { cancelToken: token, cancel } = source;
  const getPairs = async () => {
    setData({ pairs: null, isLoading: false, error: null });

    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "http://localhost:3000/binance/pairs?timeframe=" +
          timeframe +
          "&strat=" +
          strat,
        {
          cancelToken,
        }
      );

      if (res.status === 200 || res.data.status === "success") {
        setData({ pairs: res.data.pairs, isLoading: false, error: null });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      if (axios.isCancel(err)) {
        console.log("cancelled");
      } else {
        setData({ pairs: null, isLoading: false, error });
      }
    }
  };

  return [data, getPairs, cancel];
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [{ isLoading, pairs, error }, getPairs, cancel] = useFetchPairs();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // cancelling when component unmounts i.e. navigation
      cancel();
    };
  }, []);

  const onClick = () => {
    if (isLoading) {
      // cancelling when button clicked and previous request in progress
      cancel();
    }
    getPairs();
  };
  return (
    <>
      {error && <p>{error}</p>}
      <div>{pairs}</div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Click me</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. In `useFetchPairs`, when declaring `cancelToken`, shouldn't it be : `cancelToken: token` ? I did it like this, otherwise `cancelToken` is `undefined`. Even when putting messages in `cancel()`, no message logs in and I can still see all the requests being processed in the backend terminal. Shouldn't one of the `isLoading` be `true` at some point ? They are all `false` in your example. I tried playing around with your code but can't get it to work. I got to the point where I get `cancelled` from the `catch` block (in `if (axios.isCancel(err))`). Any idea ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest one more solution with custom libs ([Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-callback-axios-single-request-2rdry?file=/src/TestComponent.js)):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useAsyncCallback, E_REASON_UNMOUNTED } from "use-async-effect2";
import { CanceledError } from "c-promise2";
import cpAxios from "cp-axios";

export default function TestComponent(props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const request = useAsyncCallback(
    function* () {
      this.timeout(props.timeout);

      try {
        setText("fetching...");
        const response = yield cpAxios(props.url);
        setText(`Success: ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}`);
        // do whatever you need with the response data here 
      } catch (err) {
        CanceledError.rethrow(err, E_REASON_UNMOUNTED); //passthrough
        setText(`Failed: ${err}`);
      }
    },
    { deps: [props.url], cancelPrevious: true }
  );

  return (
    <div className="component">
      <div>{text}</div>
      <button onClick={request}>Request</button>
      <button onClick={request.cancel}>Abort</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```